Generalizing Banach's matchbox problem to multiple matchboxes
Banach's matchbox problem
Banach's matchbox problem describes two matchboxes, each initially filled with $K$ matches. Every time we need a match, we pick either box randomly with probability $1/2$. We keep picking until we find either box to be empty. The problem asks what is the probability distribution underlying the number of matches left in the other box.
My question
I would like to understand if it is possible to generalize Banach's matchbox problem to the case where, instead of two matchboxes, we have $N$ matchboxes. As before, each box is initially filled with $K$ matches. Every time we need a match, we pick it from a box selected uniformly at random. As soon as we encounter an empty box, we stop picking.
What I would like to know is the probability distribution underlying the total number of matches still present in the $C$ boxes containing the most matches.
More precisely, let's say that, as soon as I encounter an empty box, I order all remaining boxes in decreasing order of matches (fullest to most empty), then count the number of matches $M$ present in the first $C$ boxes. Is it possible to derive the probability distribution underlying $M$? If not, is it possible to at least derive a bound?
The context
I am attempting to design a distributed computing algorithm, running on $N$ computers. In brief, my algorithm unfolds in rounds. At every round, the algorithm queries a random computer, which reveals some hidden secret, out of a list of $K$ secrets that it pre-generated before the protocol started. As soon as any computer is queried for a secret it doesn't have (i.e., the $(K + 1)$-th secret, we encountered an "empty matchbox"!), the algorithm stops. Now, importantly, some of the computers are under the control of a malicious adversary, who can arbitrarily decide up to $(N - C)$ computers to control, even as the protocol is running (we say the adversary is adaptive). In brief, the probability that my algorithm will fail is $2^{-M}$, where $M$ is the total number of secrets revealed by the $C$ computers the adversary does not control. To maximize this probability, the adaptive adversary will wait until the algorithm is over, then infect the $(N - C)$ computers that revealed the most secrets, thus minimizing $M$. Equivalently, the adversary will decide not to infect the $C$ computers that revealed the least secrets (the $C$ "fullest matchboxes").
This problem is the last step in the development of a Byzantine Common Coin, a fundamental distributed computing primitive capable of powering an instance of Byzantine Consensus. Working out the algorithm was difficult but feasible, but now I am stuck on the probabilistic analysis.
My attempt
Regrettably, my attempt to generalize Banach's matchbox problem was not successful. What I thought I could do was to derive the probability distribution underlying the number of matches $B$ in any of the $(N - 1)$ boxes that don't end up being empty. Without loss of generality, let's call "X" the box that ends up being empty, let's call "Y" some other box. If we take the sequence of box picks and discard every pick that is not "X" or "Y", the number of "Y"s in-between any two "X"s, I thought, should be geometric with probability $1/2$. I was hoping to get a distribution similar to that of the other matchbox in the original problem, but after a quick Montecarlo simulation it turned out I am way off, $B$ does not seem to be distributed at all like I expected.
Disclaimer
This is a rephrasing of a question I submitted recently. Following useful pointers in the comments, it was immediately apparent that phrasing my question in terms of Banach's matchbox problem would make it far more understandable to the community. To avoid spam, I have deleted my previous, poorly phrased question. I greatly appreciate the patience of those that pointed me in the right direction, and I hope my question is well understandable now.

$\def\br#1#2{{#1 \brack #2}}$
The aim of this answer is to give you a tool which allows exact computation of the probability. Here I consider for my convenience a reverse process of inserting matches in the boxes until the attempt to insert $K+1$-th match into a box (overflow event).
The line of attack is the following. We assume that the above event happens in the $n+1$-th step, compute the corresponding probability and then sum the probabilities over all possible $n$. To avoid double-counting we split the set of matchboxes into four disjoint subsets. The first (unnamed) set contains a single matchbox. This is the very matchbox which would contain in the end $K+1$ matches. This box is necessarily filled with $K$ matches after the $n$-th step and the last ($n+1$-th) match also goes in the matchbox.
Now observe that among $C$ least filled matchboxes there is a subset of boxes which have not less matches than the other of these $C$ boxes. We denote the number of matches in these most filled of the least filled boxes as $j$ and coin the set of matchboxes filled with exactly $j$ matches as $\cal B$. The cardinality of the set will be denoted as $B$. The subset of $C$ boxes which are filled with less than $j$ matches we coin as $\cal A$ and denote its cardinality as $A$. Notice that $A < C$ and $B\ge C-A $. The last subset $\cal X$ contains all remaining boxes (i.e. boxes containing from $j+1$ to $K$ matches) so that its cardinality is $X=N-A-B-1$. The subsets $\cal A$ and $\cal X$ can in general be empty.
Let us now introduce the symbol:
$$
\br{M,m}{m_1,m_2}=x^m:\left[ \sum_{k=m_1}^{m_2}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right]^M.
$$
where $x^m:$ is the coefficient extractor operator.
Then the probability that the $C$ least filled boxes contain $M$ matches by the "overflow" event can be computed as:
$$\small
P(M;C,N,K)=\sum_{n=K}^{NK}\frac1{N^{n+1}}\frac{n!}{K!}\sum_{A=0}^{C-1}\;\sum_{B=C-A}^{N-A-1}{\small\frac{N!}{1!A!B!X!}}\sum_{j=0}^K
\br{A,M-j(C-A)}{0,j-1}\cdot\br{B,jB}{j,j}\cdot\br{X,n-M-K-j(A+B-C)} {j+1,K}.\tag1
$$
The corresponding Mathematica code is given below.
To express the probability in terms of matches $M'$ left in the $C$ most filled boxes of the original problem it is sufficient to note that $M'=CK-M$.
 Unprotect[Power];Power[0,0]=1;Protect[Power]
 F[M_,m_,m1_,m2_]:=Coefficient[Sum[x^k/k!,{k,m1,m2}]^M,x,m]
 P[M_,C_,N_,K_]:=Sum[N! n!/K!/N^n/N Sum[1/A!/B!/(N-A-B-1)! Sum[F[A,M-j(C-A),0,j-1]F[B,B j,j,j]F[N-A-B-1,n-M-K-j(A+B-C),j+1,K],{j,0,K}],{A,0,C-1},{B,C-A,N-A-1}],{n,K,N K}]

The results of numerical simulations perfectly match the formula $(1)$.

I would have never, ever, come to the solution by myself! Thank you so much!

You are welcome.
